# Read /dev/tty from within a completion function

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Why is the following code not working for completion of the `foo` command? When I source it then type `foo <Tab>`, the shell hangs and doesn't take any input until I press `^C` (which exits the command completion).

My hypothesis is that `/dev/tty` is already being read by the shell and it somehow messes with `cat` being able to read from it as well, but in that case I still need a workaround.

```
_foo() {
    _values 'foo' "$(cat < /dev/tty)"
}

compdef _foo foo
```

Note that this example is deliberately simplified: the actual use case is running a terminal interface program (think ncurses) instead of `cat`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this particular completion?

Comment: I just want to implement my own completion UI. I already have the ncurses GUI binary implemented, it works when I call it from the regular shell (even when its input is a pipe or it's invoked from a subshell, in which case I just open /dev/tty myself), the only issue is when used with completion.

Comment: Note that zsh has builtin ncurses support in its `zsh/curses` module.

Answer (score 1):

During completion, you're in the zsh line editor, so the terminal line discipline's own line editor is disabled as if you had run:

```
stty -icanon -echo
```

In that mode, `cat` cannot exit as there's no way you can signify it the end of input (`^D` is part of the `icanon` line discipline's line editor behaviour) and you won't see the echo of what you type.

You could do:

```
_foo() {
  _values 'foo' "$(
    {
      s=$(stty -g)
      stty sane
      cat
      stty $s
    } < /dev/tty)"
  zle -I
}
```

That is, put the terminal device in the state expected by `cat` (where you can press `^D` on an empty line or twice to end the input) before running `cat` and restore it afterwards. And we tell zle it has to redraw its prompt and buffer as the echo of what you'd type within the line discipline line editor would mess things up (`zle -I` to *invalidate*).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too simplified, `cat` will read from `/dev/tty` for a good long while. With a `_foo` completion of

```
#compdef foo
_values 'foo' "$(promptfor)"
```

and a `promptfor` of

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set fh [open /dev/tty r+]
stty raw -echo
set key [read $fh 1]            ;# read from tty
puts stdout $key                ;# to ZSH
flush stdout
stty -raw echo
```

my ZSH on `foo`<kbd>tab</kbd> will then complete whatever key is then pressed while `promptfor` runs.

If you have a daemon of sorts sitting around, then you'll probably need something fancier like a socket that ZSH and your daemon can use to carry out any necessary communications; `read` in ZSH can read from an arbitrary file descriptor or coprocess...